# What would be the proper garbage collection mechanism in a DB?

Tags: java, mysql, performance

I store some data in DB for my future usage. After using those data, i would like to remove those data from database. 
What would be the effective way to do this? 
I need to select data and clean them in an efficient manner. Im using java as my language and MySql as my storage DB.

Any ideas would be appreciated..

Comment: What are the conditions that would allow you to select the data?

Comment: Err, 'DELETE'? What's the question here?

Comment: I have the primary key of the data stored in the DB, which needs to be cleaned..

Comment: Simply delete the data once used. You can do the cleanup in a separate thread if required.

Comment: @EJP yes i want to delete data in an efficient manner

Comment: @Ratha delete in efficient manner means what?just simply write delete from table(if you want to delete only records not table) if you want to delete all records else put a where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is only going to be used once, then it can be deleted.  If all data in the table can be deleted then the most efficient means would be to either drop the table or to truncate it.  If neither of these are possible then deletion by PK would be the next best method.